# How to create a RecoverableWriter in Flink for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, apache-flink

I wanted to use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) to write (*sink*) elements of `DataStream` from my streaming job using [`StreamingFileSink`](https://git.io/fA1io).

For doing that, I used [Google Cloud Storage connector](https://git.io/fA1ii) for Hadoop as an implementation of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`, and used [`HadoopFileSystem` as an implementation of `org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem`](https://git.io/fA1iH) that wraps the *hadoop FileSystem* class for Flink.

I included the following dependencies in my gradle file:

- `compile(`**`"com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:1.9.4-hadoop2"`**`)`
- `compile(`**`"org.apache.flink:flink-connector-filesystem_2.11:1.6.0"`**`)`
- `provided(`**`"org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2:1.6.0"`**`)`

Now, from what I understand looking at the sources <sup>[[1]](https://git.io/fA1PT)</sup>  <sup>[[2]](https://git.io/fA1Pt)</sup>  <sup>[[3]](https://git.io/fA1Pm)</sup>, Flink dynamically loads the implementations of [`FileSystemFactory`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.6.0/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/core/fs/FileSystemFactory.java) at runtime (via `java.util.ServiceLoader`) and also loads the [`HadoopFsFactory`](https://git.io/fA1PG) at runtime (via *reflection*, if it finds Hadoop in classpath) which it then uses to create instances of `FileSystem`.

The issue I faced was that the default [`RecoverableWriter`](https://git.io/fA1PP) for Hadoop compatibility package only supports `hdfs` file scheme (I use `gs`) and hence [throws an error at runtime](https://git.io/fA1P1).

So, I `extended` the `HadoopFileSystem` (I called `GCSFileSystem`) and `@overrided` the [`FileSystem#createRecoverableWriter()`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/api/java/org/apache/flink/core/fs/FileSystem.html#createRecoverableWriter--) to return a custom implementation of [`RecoverableWriter`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/api/java/org/apache/flink/core/fs/RecoverableWriter.html) which then handle the details of recovery, etc. and also created a corresponding `FileSystemFactory` class (the class is decorated with `@AutoService` and thus should be discoverable by `ServiceLoader`).

The setup works well locally and on a local docker cluster (actually the GCS connector throws an error due to lack of authorization, but that's fine since it means that the `FileSystem` is loaded and running) but it fails when I deploy it to a docker cluster running on Google Compute Engine.

On GCE, the default `HadoopFileSystem` gets loaded and throws the exception as the scheme is `gs` and not `hdfs`, but my assumption is that it should have loaded my implementation of the factory and thus this error shouldn't have arised.

I am on Flink **v1.6.0** and running as [long running session cluster on Docker using **docker-flink**](https://github.com/docker-flink/docker-flink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the *last line* of the OP!!

I was running on a *long living Session-cluster* and by the time my `job.jar` was executed the `FileSystem` initialization had already been done and the factories were already loaded! and so, no *initialization* calls were made when I added my Job.

The solution? There are a few ways depending on how you deploy your job:

- **Standalone:** Add the jar containing `FileSystem` implementation to the `lib/` directory
- **Cluster (`manual`):** Add the jar containing `FileSystem` implementation to the `lib/` directory of your `zip` or image or whatever.
- **Cluster (`docker`)(`long-living`):** Create a custom container image and add the jar to the `lib/` directory of that image.
- **Cluster (`docker`)(`per-job-session`):** Create a custom container image and add all the jars (containing `FileSystem` and your job, etc.) to the `lib/` directory, [read more about **per-job** session here.](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/deployment/docker.html)